# Visual Studio (2015) fpermissive equivalent flag

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, compiler-flags

In VS2015 is there an equivalent flag of GCC -fpermissive?
That's for a cpp application
Thanks
S.

Comment: I hope not, `-fpermissive` is a terrible idea. The scope of changes it introduces over non-permissive mode is too big and can't be controlled easily.

Comment: What specific issue are you trying to work around?

Comment: So, essentially, an option along the lines of *"Treat errors as warnings"*? No, this does not exist. If you have non-conforming code, just fix the code. Don't tell the compiler to shut up so that you can ship buggy code to customers.

Comment: The workaround has a reason (as always): I have an high level source code which is translated into C or C++. My particular problem is that when I have a value `unsigned int *` which is passed to a function that expects an `int *`. So in GCC I can use -fpermissive, with VS I cannot build the program. Of course I know that this is a buggy code. This come from a big collaborative project... Fixes like that will (must) be solved in a next step.

Comment: @simalps: "Fixes like that will (must) be solved in a next step" - and I felt a great disturbance in the Force, as if millions of voices suddenly cried out in terror at the increased technical debt in the Universe, and then were silenced :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo :) exactly. this is a quote i’ll print stick in somewhere, definitely

Answer (score 1):

The theoretical equivalent is `/Ze`.

However, this allows Microsoft-specific extensions, whereas `-fpermissive` allows GCC-specific extensions. If you want your code to be portable, write portable code. It's that simple.

Comment: /Ze in VS2017 with MSVC 19 gives me "cl : Command line warning D9035 : option 'Ze' has been deprecated and will be removed in a future release"

Comment: @parsley72: Good to hear.

Comment: @parsley72: I rolled back your change. `-fpermissive` is the GCC switch, as mentioned in the question. It's not at all the same as `/permissive-` in VS2017. For starters, it has the opposite meaning.

Answer (score 1):

VC++ compiler permissive by default, but you can disable it using compiler flag [`/permissive-`](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/11/16/permissive-switch/) starting with VS2015 Update 3

Comment: `/permissive-` is being extended in VS2017 https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/11/16/permissive-switch/

Comment: I *have* vs2k15u3 but, when I enter `/permissive-` into the "Project properties | C/C++ | Command Line | Aditional Options" field, I get: `2>cl : Command line warning D9002: ignoring unknown option '/permissive-'`

Comment: @paxdiablo What exact version do you use?

Comment: @Pi: fron the vs2k15pro help/about: Version 14.0.25431.01 Update 3.