# Wl,--stack,4194304 error Visual Studio/CMake

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, compiler-errors, cmake

So I have built an open source project Using CMake and opened it in Visual Studio but I get this error:

> Command line error D8021: invalid numeric argument
>   '/Wl,--stack,4194304'

My CMakeLists.txt that has this:

> if(WIN32)
>       set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wl,--stack,4194304 -fpermissive") endif()

I am not sure what is this or how it can be fixed. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are giving your Visual Studio compiler switches that are intended for GCC.

```
if (WIN32)
  if ("${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID}" STREQUAL "GNU")
     set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wl,--stack,4194304 -fpermissive")
  elseif(MSVC)
    # add options for Visual C/C++ Compiler here
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} /F 4194304")
  endif()
endif()
```

See also [In cmake, how can I test if the compiler is Clang?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10046114/in-cmake-how-can-i-test-if-the-compiler-is-clang) how to reliable identify your compiler.

For the permissive flag please see [Visual Studio (2015) fpermissive equivalent flag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36119137/visual-studio-2015-fpermissive-equivalent-flag) .

**Edit**: Added more reliable compiler check for GCC according to discussion.

Comment: So no equivalent for it for MSVC?

Comment: There is one. Just added it to the example.

Comment: Any idea why I keep getting Command line error D8004: '/W' requires an argument ?

Comment: Then please try `"${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID}" STREQUAL "GNU"` instead of `CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCC`.